# "got a question about the site itself?" should be capitalized

Tags: feature-request, bug, private-beta, notification-bar, capitalization

On a beta site such as Beer.StackExchange, you would see

> got a question about the site itself? meta.beer is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.

Well, the `g` in `got` should be capitalized, the `b` in `beer` should probably be capitalized (because it's a proper noun), and possibly even `meta` should be too.

Comment: Apparently, not capitalizing things is chic.  Check out the close banner on any closed question for evidence of this chicness (although, to be fair, none of those are complete sentences, and `got milk?` is not capitalized either).

Comment: I changed it to "got a questions about the site itself" just so we have at least one valid pluralization bug. You're welcome. (all kidding aside, I believe this rests in the process that actually brings up a new site. I'll find out for sure).

Comment: @TimPost I just noticed the banner on [Drones and Model Aircraft Stack Exchange](https://drones.stackexchange.com/) still reads "got a question. . ." with a small "g". Is there any chance that someone will take another look at this feature request/bug report?

Comment: @Brahadeesh I agree. [Stack Overflow's own design reference](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-sentence-casing) says that calls-to-action should use "sentence casing", meaning capitalizing the first word of a sentence. The reference was probably created much later than this banner though.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Improve Meta awareness banner on private beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376710/335251)