# Improve Meta awareness banner on private beta sites

Tags: feature-request, wording, private-beta, notification-bar, capitalization

Sites in private beta ([current example](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/) – [screenshot for when it reaches public beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bEYK.png)) have a yellow banner on all pages making users aware of the Meta site:

> got a question about the site itself? [proofassistants.meta](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/) is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.

I think it looks better if the first sentence uses 'proper' grammar and is in sentence case, and the link title is changed to the name of the meta site:

> Do you have a question about the site itself? [Proof Assistants Meta](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/) is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.

Comment: I'd shorten the first sentence to just "Have a question...". "Do you" sounds a bit too wordy.

Comment: I suspect this banner message basically hasn't been changed in ages, so the formatting hasn't been updated to be in line with the [Stacks guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/) yet.